# How to improve the accuracy of prediction in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, prediction, train-test-split

I want to predict a parameter based on **3 features** and **1 target**. Here is my input file (data.csv):

```
feature.1   feature.2   feature.3   target
    1           1          1        0.0625
    0.5         0.5        0.5      0.125
    0.25        0.25       0.25     0.25
    0.125       0.125      0.125    0.5
    0.0625      0.0625     0.0625   1
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from collections import *
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

features = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

features.head()
features_name = ['feature.1' , 'feature.2' , 'feature.3']
target_name = ['target']

X = features[features_name]
y = features[target_name]

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1, random_state = 42)

linear_regression_model = LinearRegression()
linear_regression_model.fit(X_train,y_train)

#Here is where I want to predict the target value for these inputs for 3 features
new_data  = OrderedDict([('feature.1',0.375) ,('feature.2',0.375),('feature.3',0.375) ])

new_data = pd.Series(new_data).values.reshape(1,-1)
ss = linear_regression_model.predict(new_data)
print (ss)
```

According to the trend, **I expect to get a value around 0.1875** if I give 0.375 as input for all of the features. However the code predicts this:

```
[[0.44203368]]
```

Which is not correct. I do not know where the problem is. Does anybody know how I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: All your training data points happen to have all 3 features *equal*,hence raising possible collinearity issues; if this is always the case, you should just get rid from all features but one. If not, you should include some data points in your traning set where this condition does not hold...

Comment: This collinearity in your features will lead to problems with the assumptions of the linear regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is not linear. I have plotted just one dimension since the features are identical:

[image]

Approximating a Non-Linear function by a LinearRegression model creates bad results, like you experienced. You could try to model a better fitting function and fit its parameters with scipy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html